# Is "to have sense/no sense" correct?

Tags: false-friends

A person I know, who is not a native English speaker (just like me, I must add) always uses the expression "to have sense" instead of "to make sense", because in Spanish that expression literally translates as "to have sense", which is correct. As a real life example, he would say

> It has no sense to develop this feature

It just sounds so ugly and bad to me, and I believe it is a false friend, but I do not want to say anything because like other times, this might be a correct expression, just a very uncommon one. Am I right believing this is a false friend, or do those expressions mean exactly the same?

Comment: You are right. The correct expression is 'It makes no sense'.

Comment: Yes, make. If I'm reading you correctly "to make" translates into "to have" in Spanish. Is it idiomatic or does the Spanish "have" contain some sense of "making," or "creating"?

Comment: No, it translates like that in this case because "to make sense" translates more accurately to "to have some meaning" in Spanish, so I guessed they believed that, since in Spanish something "HAS a meaning", in English something "HAS sense"

Comment: This may be a better question for ELL (https://ell.stackexchange.com/).  But to me, the short answer is that a person *has* sense, and a concept *makes* sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes – normally you would say, "It makes sense," but with the proliferation of foreign speakers saying "It has sense," the latter may become a more usual expression. For native speakers from some areas, you might hear someone say a person "has no sense", meaning they are not very bright. Also people say, "there is some sense to that," meaning it makes sense to a certain degree.

Comment: Hello, 470. I agree with what you've said (so I've tidied it). But ELU likes answers that have some corroborating evidence (linked and attributed dictionary definitions, examples from articles ...). In this case, supplying that might be quite demanding.

Comment: I don't disagree, though maybe someone else will have a more detailed answer before I get the time for that.